# Move assignment operator; attempting to reference a deleted function. How can I resolve this?

Tags: c++, function, move

This is the function that's of issue:

> > Bucket& Bucket::operator=(Bucket&& otherBucket);

I want to call it. However, I cannot and I get errors:

> Error 'SortedList &SortedList::operator =(const SortedList &)':
>   attempting to reference a deleted function tests.h 25

**Tests.h:**

```
#include "sortedlist.h"
#include <iostream>

void runTests() {
    cout << "***********************************************" << endl;
    cout << "Testing sortedlist" << endl;
    cout << "***********************************************" << endl;
    cout << "Testing sort >>" << endl;
    cout << "***********************************************" << endl;
    vector<double> v =
    { 0.10, 0.90, 0.15, 0.95, 0.85,
        0.73, 0.56, 0.32, 0.87, 0.11,
        0.67, 0.34, 0.43, 0.61, 0.03 };
    SortedList sortedListA;
    cout << "BEFORE sortList function call: " << endl << endl;
    sortedListA.testPrint();
    sortedListA.sortList(v);
    cout << "AFTER sortList function call: " << endl << endl;
    sortedListA.testPrint();
    cout << endl << "Using move assignmnet operator: " << endl << endl;
    SortedList sortedListB;
    cout << "Before move assignment operator call: " << endl << endl;
    sortedListB.testPrint();
    cout << "After move assignment operator call: " << endl << endl;
    sortedListB = move(sortedListA); // This is where the error occurs!
}
```

> sortedListB = move(sortedListA); // This is where the error occurs!

I'm attempting to use or call the move assignment operator in my class. However, it's not calling it. SortedList **inherits** from Bucket class and here's the full **context**:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "tests.h"
#include "sortedlist.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    runTests();

    cout << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Bucket.h**

```
#ifndef BUCKET_H
#define BUCKET_H    

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    Node() : item(0.0), link(nullptr) {}
    Node(double newItem, Node *newLink) : item(newItem), link(newLink) {}
    Node* getLink() const { return link; }
    double getItem() const { return item; }
    void setItem(double newItem) { item = newItem; }
    void setLink(Node *newLink) { link = newLink; }
    ~Node() {}
private:
    double item;
    Node *link;
};


class Bucket
{
public:
    Bucket();
    void insert(double value);
    void moveAppend(Bucket& otherBucket);
    void testPrint() const;
    void print() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    Bucket& operator=(Bucket&& otherBucket);
    void deleteBucket();
    ~Bucket();
private:
    Node *ptrToFirst;
    Node *ptrToLast;
    int numberOfElements;
};

#endif
```

**Bucket.cpp: This is where the problem is. Go down to the move assignment operator overloaded function, I commented on that one:**

> Bucket& Bucket::operator=(Bucket&& otherBucket);

```
#include "bucket.h"

Bucket::Bucket() {
    ptrToFirst = nullptr;
    ptrToLast = nullptr;
    numberOfElements = 0;
}

void Bucket::insert(double value) {
    if (numberOfElements != 0) {
        Node *newNode = new Node(value, nullptr);

        if (value < ptrToFirst->getItem()) {
            newNode->setLink(ptrToFirst);
            ptrToFirst = newNode;
        }
        else if (value > ptrToLast->getItem()) {
            ptrToLast->setLink(newNode);
            ptrToLast = newNode;
        }
        else if (value != ptrToFirst->getItem()) { // Prevents inserting duplicates of a value.
            Node *current = ptrToFirst;

            while (value > current->getLink()->getItem()) {
                current = current->getLink();
            }

            if (current->getLink()->getItem() != value) { // Prevents inserting duplicates of a value.
                newNode->setLink(current->getLink()); 
                current->setLink(newNode);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        ptrToFirst = new Node(value, ptrToLast);
        ptrToLast = ptrToFirst;
    }

    ++numberOfElements;
}

void Bucket::moveAppend(Bucket& otherBucket) {
    if (this != &otherBucket) {
        if (numberOfElements == 0) {
            delete ptrToFirst;
            ptrToFirst = move(otherBucket.ptrToFirst);
            otherBucket.ptrToFirst = nullptr;
            delete ptrToLast;
            ptrToLast = move(otherBucket.ptrToLast);
            otherBucket.ptrToLast = nullptr;

            numberOfElements = move(otherBucket.numberOfElements);
            otherBucket.numberOfElements = move(0);
        }
        else {
            Node *otherBucketFirstNode = move(otherBucket.ptrToFirst);
            otherBucket.ptrToFirst = nullptr;
            ptrToLast->setLink(otherBucketFirstNode);
            ptrToLast = move(otherBucket.ptrToLast);
            otherBucket.ptrToLast = nullptr;

            numberOfElements = move(numberOfElements + otherBucket.numberOfElements);
            otherBucket.numberOfElements = move(0);
        }
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Cannot append this bucket to the same bucket." << endl;
    }


}

void Bucket::testPrint() const {
    cout << "Pointer to first: " << ptrToFirst << endl;
    cout << "Pointer to last: " << ptrToLast << endl;

    if (ptrToFirst != nullptr && ptrToLast != nullptr) {
        cout << "Value of ptrToFirst: " << ptrToFirst->getItem() << endl;
        cout << "Value of ptrToLast: " << ptrToLast->getItem() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Number of elements: " << numberOfElements << endl;
    cout << "Contents of bucket: " << endl;

    Node *current = ptrToFirst;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        cout << current->getItem() << " ";
        current = current->getLink();
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void Bucket::print() const {
    Node *current = ptrToFirst;

    while (current != nullptr) {
        cout << current->getItem() << " ";
        current = current->getLink();
    }
}

bool Bucket::isEmpty() const {
    return (numberOfElements == 0);
}

void Bucket::deleteBucket() {
    Node *trailingCurrent;

    while (ptrToFirst != nullptr) {
        trailingCurrent = ptrToFirst;
        ptrToFirst = ptrToFirst->getLink();
        delete trailingCurrent;
        trailingCurrent = nullptr;
    }

    ptrToLast = nullptr;
    numberOfElements = 0;
}

Bucket& Bucket::operator=(Bucket&& otherBucket) {
    cout << "Move assignment operator has been called." << endl;

    // This is what I want it to call, but it's not calling it. Why?

    return *this;
}

Bucket::~Bucket() {
    deleteBucket();
}
```

**SortedList.h:**

```
#ifndef SORTEDLIST_H
#define SORTEDLIST_H    

#include "bucketsort.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class SortedList : public Bucket
{
public:
    SortedList();
    void sortList(const vector <double>& list);
    ~SortedList();
private:
};

#endif
```

**SortedList.cpp:**

```
#include "sortedlist.h"
#include <iostream>

SortedList::SortedList() {}

void SortedList::sortList(const vector <double>& list) {
    BucketSort bucketA;
    bucketA.insert(list);
    bucketA.createSortedList(*this);
}

SortedList::~SortedList() {}
```

**BucketSort.h:**

```
#ifndef BUCKETSORT_H
#define BUCKETSORT_H    

#include "bucket.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int DEFAULTCAPACITY = 10;

class BucketSort
{
public:
    // Constructors:
    BucketSort();
    // Functions:
    void print() const;
    void insert(const vector <double>& v) const;
    void createSortedList(Bucket& a);
    //
    ~BucketSort();
private:
    Bucket ** a;
};

#endif
```

**BucketSort.cpp:**

```
#include "bucketsort.h"

BucketSort::BucketSort() {
    a = new Bucket*[DEFAULTCAPACITY]();
}

void BucketSort::print() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULTCAPACITY; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != nullptr) { 
            a[i]->print();
        }
    }
}

void BucketSort::insert(const vector <double>& v) const {
    int index;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        index = v[i] * 10;

        if (a[index] == nullptr) {
            Bucket* newBucket = new Bucket;
            a[index] = newBucket;
        }

        a[index]->insert(v[i]);
    }
}

void BucketSort::createSortedList(Bucket& thisBucket){
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULTCAPACITY; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != nullptr && !a[i]->isEmpty()) {
            thisBucket.moveAppend(*a[i]);
        }
    }
}

BucketSort::~BucketSort() {
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULTCAPACITY; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != nullptr) {
            a[i]->deleteBucket();
        }
    }

    delete a;
    a = nullptr;
}
```

Help?

Comment: `SortedList &SortedList::operator =(const SortedList &)` is not `Bucket& Bucket::operator=(Bucket&& otherBucket)`. You are getting confused about two different functions.

Comment: That's what the compiler error is complaining about. However, I don't have that function (at least) I looked? So what can I do to resolve this issue then???

Comment: Best way to solve a missing function error is to add the missing function.

Comment: I've already done that. What happens then is that it'll call that function instead. What I really want is for it to call the move assignment operator in Bucket.cpp. How can I make that possible? I don't know what to try but I've been doing several things. They don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SortedList` is not the same as `Bucket`. You've written a move assignment operator for `Bucket` but not for `SortedList`. You've given `SortedList` a custom destructor which prevents the implicit compiler-generated move assignment operator and copy constructor for `SortedList` from being generated, and thus they are deleted functions, hence the error message when trying to copy-assign `SortedList`. See [special member functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) for more details.

---

The fix is simply to write a copy-assignment operator or move-assignment operator for `SortedList`:

```
SortedList& SortedList::operator=(const SortedList& other){
    // TODO: perform the copy
    return *this;
}
```

Or:

```
SortedList& SortedList::operator=(SortedList&& other){
    // TODO: perform the move
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I finally understood it. I needed to use or construct a bucket and then use the move assignment specifically on a bucket instead. Thanks so much, clear and concise!